# Django. How to show and hide DIV based on the selection of the dropdown menu?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a dropdown menu and I want to show and hide DIVs based on the selection of that dropdown menu. I have duplicated fields in templates because I do not know the better way to handle, so if someone can suggest me simpler way to code, I will appreciate it.

The code I wrote is below

```
Template(html)

<div id="pack-method" class="col-sm-30">
   {{ form.item_packmethod|as_crispy_field }}
</div>
<div id="hidden2-1">
  <div class="col-sm-20">
    {{form.pallet_count|as_crispy_field}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-20">
    {{form.pallet_width|as_crispy_field}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-20">
    {{form.pallet_height|as_crispy_field}}
  </div>
</div>
<div id="hidden2-2">
  <div class="col-sm-20">
    {{form.pallet_count|as_crispy_field}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-20">
    {{form.pallet_width|as_crispy_field}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-20">
    {{form.pallet_height|as_crispy_field}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-20">
    {{form.pallet_depth|as_crispy_field}}
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#hidden2-1').css({
       'display': 'none'
    });
    $('#hidden2-2').css({
       'display': 'none'
    });
    $('#pack-method').on('change', function() {
       if (this.value === 'Pallet') {
           $('#hidden2-1').show();
           $('#hidden2-2').hide();
       }
       else if ($(this).val() == 'Rack') {
           $('#hidden2-1').hide();
           $('#hidden2-2').show();
       }
       else if ($(this).val() == 'Box') {
           $('#hidden2-1').hide();
           $('#hidden2-2').show();
       }
       else {
           $('#hidden2-1').hide();
           $('#hidden2-2').hide();
       }
    });
</script>

Forms.py

BLANK_CHOICE = (('', '----------'),)
PALLET = 'Pallet'
RACK = 'Rack'
BOX = 'Box'

PACK_TYPE = (
    (PALLET, 'Pallet'),
    (RACK, 'Rack'),
    (BOX, 'Box'),
)

item_packmethod = forms.ChoiceField(label="Pack Method", choices = BLANK_CHOICE + PACK_TYPE,required=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. 
For those who might be interested, I changed

```
$('#pack-method').on('change', function() {
       if (this.value === 'Pallet') {
           $('#hidden2-1').show();
           $('#hidden2-2').hide();
       }
...
}

to

$('select').on('change', function() {
       var a = $(this).val();
       if (a === 'Pallet') {
          $('#hidden2-1').show();
          $('#hidden2-2').hide();
       }
...
}
```